# Wildfly (14) - Not as Datasource defined MySQL DB-Connection that uses SSL

Tags: java, ssl, connection, wildfly

We have a Java application that get's deployed as .ear to a **Wildfly 14** webserver. This application uses a **MSSQL datasource, configured in the standalone.xml, that does *not* use SSL**. Also the **client connections do *not* use SSL** to connect to / work with the deployed application.

Inside this application we can configure **other database connections that are not stated as datasource in the standalone.xml. One of those now needs to connect using SSL.** What we did so far is:

- We created a **jks keystore** in our *OpenJDK11/lib/security folder*.
- The standalone.conf.bat got extended and now adds the following JAVA_OPTS:
  **-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=*password***
- When we try to connect to the database that needs SSL verification we use the following connection string: **jdbc:mysql://*serverip*:3306/*schema*?useSSL=true&trustServerCertificate=true**

We also tried without the **trustServerCertificate=true** part.

When starting the Wildfly Server we can see that those additional JAVA_OPTS got accepted and are printed out in the server.log.

Our result when trying to establish a connection is a MySQL Java Exception as follows:

```
2019-10-24 14:57:41,346 ERROR 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 1 milliseconds ago.
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor125.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1116)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:105)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.negotiateSSLConnection(MysqlIO.java:5148)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1689)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1276)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2395)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2428)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2213)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:797)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:389)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:677)
    at java.sql/java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:189)
    at deployment.ablex.ear.server.core.jar//com.arm.asale.server.core.local.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:75)
    at deployment.ablex.ear.entity.meta.jar//com.arm.ablex.entity.util.JdbcConnUtilBase.open(JdbcConnUtilBase.java:44)
    at deployment.ablex.ear.entity.meta.jar//com.arm.ablex.entity.util.SqlStatement.<init>(SqlStatement.java:169)
    at deployment.ablex.ear.server_pdi.jar//com.arm.ablex.server.pdi.jdbc.local.ExchangerJdbcBasics.selectMetaData(ExchangerJdbcBasics.java:98)
    at deployment.ablex.ear.server_pdi.jar//com.arm.ablex.server.pdi.jdbc.ExchangeJdbcAdminSessionBean.selectMetaDataOverJdbc(ExchangeJdbcAdminSessionBean.java:173)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.interceptors.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:101)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:40)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:237)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:362)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:144)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:509)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.0.5.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:81)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.common@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.StartupAwaitInterceptor.processInvocation(StartupAwaitInterceptor.java:22)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbSuspendInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbSuspendInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:60)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:438)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.6.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:619)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:422)
    at org.jboss.invocation@1.5.1.Final//org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:53)
    at org.jboss.as.ee@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:198)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-private@1.6.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.SecurityIdentity.runAsFunctionEx(SecurityIdentity.java:382)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.invokeWithIdentity(AssociationImpl.java:556)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.invokeMethod(AssociationImpl.java:537)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3@14.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.AssociationImpl.lambda$receiveInvocationRequest$0(AssociationImpl.java:195)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.2.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at com.mysql//com.mysql.jdbc.ExportControlled.transformSocketToSSLSocket(ExportControlled.java:90)
    ... 89 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:239)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:190)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:108)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    ... 92 more
```

When we use the same approach in a plain Java program that just get's executed (and not deployed on a Server) the connection can be established. This program uses the same Java Options during startup as explained above. The connection string does not differ as well.

Google did not help, the only topics we found were about *datasources with SSL* or *client to server SSL connection*.

Our current guess is that we somehow have to give the Wildfly System knowledge about this keystore because it might not find it for some reason. What we have to avoid is that all connections try to connect using SSL after an adjustment.

My question is: Does this approach have a chance to work and is there a way to give the Wildfly knowledge about the jks keystore? And if so: How are we able to do so? Maybe we went in a wrong direction and we have to work on a different configuration?

Cheers.

@Edit:
we tried adding the keystore/truststore paths to the Wildfly starting Parameters, but it did not work as expected. We tried different combinations as well (just trustore path and no keystore or as second option both stores):

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\java\lib\security\truststore
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=password
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\java\lib\security\keystore
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password
```

Comment: You could try setting the path to the keystore with system property too

Comment: Thank you for your advice, we tried that but it did not work as expected. Updated the question due to our results.